# Clicking on the buttons doesn't do anything

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making this code in Windows Forms for a school project. Its basically a mind game in which you have to remember the positions of numbers in squares. The problem is that I'm stuck on the part of clicking the buttons which display numbers. Here's my code (updated version still no result of clicking a button):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int MaxLevel = 25;
        private const int ShowTimeMilliseconds = 1000;
        private const int InitialTimeSeconds = 5;

        private Button[] buttons;
        private int currentLevel;
        private int currentPlayerLevel;
        private bool gameStarted;
        private bool showingNumbers;
        private Timer showNumbersTimer;
        private Timer gameTimer;
        private Random random;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeButtons();
            random = new Random();
        }

        private void InitializeButtons()
        {
            buttons = new Button[] { button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12, button13, button14, button15, button16, button17, button18, button19, button20, button21, button22, button23, button24, button25, button26 };

            foreach (var button in buttons)
            {
                button.Click += Button_Click;
            }

            startButton.Click += startButton_Click;
        }

        private void InitializeGame()
        {
            currentPlayerLevel = 1;
            currentLevel = 1;
            UpdateLevelLabel();
        }

        private void StartGame()
        {
            gameStarted = true;
            gameTimer = new Timer();
            gameTimer.Interval = 1000;
            gameTimer.Tick += GameTimer_Tick;
            gameTimer.Start();

            InitializeGame();

            int randomButtonIndex = random.Next(0, currentLevel * currentLevel);

            foreach (Button button in buttons)
            {
                button.Text = string.Empty;
            }

            ShuffleButtons();

            buttons[randomButtonIndex].Text = "1";

            StartNewLevel();

            startButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void ShuffleButtons()
        {
            int n = buttons.Length;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = random.Next(n + 1);
                Button value = buttons[k];
                buttons[k] = buttons[n];
                buttons[n] = value;
            }
        }

        private void StartNewLevel()
        {
            showingNumbers = true;
            DisableButtons();

            List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, currentLevel).ToList();
            numbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToList();

            int randomButtonIndex = random.Next(0, currentLevel);

            for (int i = 0; i < currentLevel; i++)
            {
                buttons[i].Text = numbers[i].ToString();
                buttons[i].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                buttons[i].Enabled = true;
            }

            buttons[randomButtonIndex].Text = "1";

            showNumbersTimer = new Timer();
            showNumbersTimer.Interval = ShowTimeMilliseconds;
            showNumbersTimer.Tick += ShowNumbersTimer_Tick;
            showNumbersTimer.Start();
        }

        private void EndLevel()
        {
            showingNumbers = false;
            showNumbersTimer.Stop();
            ClearButtons();
            EnableButtons();
        }

        private void EndGame()
        {
            gameStarted = false;
            gameTimer.Stop();
            currentPlayerLevel = 0;
            UpdateLevelLabel();
            MessageBox.Show("Game Over!");
        }

        private void UpdateLevelLabel()
        {
            textBox1.Text = $"Level: {currentPlayerLevel}";
        }

        private void ShowNumbersTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Array.FindIndex(buttons, button => button.Text == "1");
            buttons[index].BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            buttons[index].Text = string.Empty;

            EndLevel();
        }

        private int initialTimeSeconds = InitialTimeSeconds;

        private void GameTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            initialTimeSeconds--;

            if (initialTimeSeconds < 0)
            {
                gameTimer.Stop();
                EndGame();
            }

            UpdateTimerLabel();
        }

        private void UpdateTimerLabel()
        {
            textBox2.Text = initialTimeSeconds.ToString();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;

            if (showingNumbers)
                return;

            int expectedNumber = currentPlayerLevel;

            if (button.Text == expectedNumber.ToString())
            {
                currentPlayerLevel++;

                if (currentPlayerLevel > MaxLevel)
                {
                    gameTimer.Stop();
                    EndGame();
                }
                else if (currentPlayerLevel > currentLevel)
                {
                    currentLevel++;
                    UpdateLevelLabel();
                    StartNewLevel();
                }
            }
        }

        private void DisableButtons()
        {
            foreach (Button button in buttons)
            {
                button.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void EnableButtons()
        {
            foreach (Button button in buttons)
            {
                button.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void ClearButtons()
        {
            foreach (Button button in buttons)
            {
                button.Text = string.Empty;
                button.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            }
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!gameStarted)
            {
                InitializeGame();
                StartGame();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also some images of how the form looks when started:

[program when started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuz9I.png)
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gju8.png)

I tried adding the buttons with code which did not work well and I'm expecting the program to allow me to click on the buttons and actually work.

Comment: Does `Button_Click()` actually fire for all of the buttons in your array? Add `Console.WriteLine(button.Name);` after the `Button button = (Button)sender;
` line to see.

Comment: I don't see a `... .Click += Button_Click` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For a basic button or other control, you connect the control to the event handlers via the Control's properties pane in the Visual Studio designer. But you're getting just a bit fancy, where you want all these buttons to use the same method. In that case, you can wire up the event handlers in code:

```
private void InitializeButtons()
{
    buttons = new Button[] { button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12, button13, button14, button15, button16, button17, button18, button19, button20, button21, button22, button23, button24, button25, button26 };

    foreach(var button in buttons)
    {
        button.Click += this.Button_Click;
    }
}
```

*Make sure this `InitializeButtons()` method is only called once!*

---

Also, this makes me sad:

```
buttons.OrderBy(b => Guid.NewGuid())
```

It's going to be just a little worse than O(n) most of the time, but it's possible to get into rare pathologic cases where this takes a loooooong time to finish. Instead, look up how to do a Fisher-Yates shuffle, which is guaranteed as exactly O(n).

---

This also makes me sad:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

The line itself is fine, but it's in the wrong place. Rather than scoped to a method, you are much better off when the PRNG is long-lived. Scope it to the class (form) or application, instead.

Comment: Thanks i did put all the things you mentioned into my code, but the buttons still do nothing when clicked. And also I'm new to this can I somehow show you the updated version of my code?

Comment: You can edit the question to include the modification and any new behavior. If you've made this change, though, at a guess I'd expect the method IS running, but it's hitting this line right away with an unexpected result: `if (showingNumbers) return;` You may want `if (!showingNumbers)` here.

Comment: `buttons.Click ` is a typo. Must be `button.Click`

Comment: The `new EventHandler()` part can be omitted for brevity.

Comment: @ThomasWeller duh, I should have seen that already (both of them) :o

Comment: fixed both, but i still cant click on the damn buttons

Answer (score 0):

To handle the clicking Event on a button, you can double click the button in your Form1.cs[Design] file. It will add the eventHandler in the: `InitializeComponent();`
like so: `this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);`
It's good practice not to modify the InitializeComponent file, but it is still possible for you to just change the line with this:
`this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Click);` this will call you function Button_Click() when button1 is pressed, you can then to this to all your buttons.

Alternatively (and best practics), you can modify your function `InitializeButtons()`  to this:

```
private void InitializeButtons()
        {
            buttons = new Button[] { button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12, button13, button14, button15, button16, button17, button18, button19, button20, button21, button22, button23, button24, button25, button26 };
            foreach(var button in buttons)
            {
                button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Click);
            }
            startButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.startButton_Click);
        }
```

It will create the EventHandler for each button in buttons, and when you click a button it will call you function `Button_Click();`

Comment: isn't this doing the same thing?

private void InitializeButtons()
        {
            buttons = new Button[] { button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12, button13, button14, button15, button16, button17, button18, button19, button20, button21, button22, button23, button24, button25, button26 };

            foreach (var button in buttons)
            {
                button.Click += new EventHandler(this.Button_Click);
            }
        }

Comment: Yes it those. Also, button1 is not included in your Array. But if you put a breakPoint in your function `Button_Click()` by clicking in the left marging (left to the line number) it will stop the execution in the function, then you can follow the code path with the arrow at the top. Button2 to button 26 will fire the  function `Button_Click()`

Comment: Thanks I edited the original post with the updated version of my code if you wanna check it out, but still no result. 
Edit:
Also added some images of my form when started and the design of you wanna check that out as well

Comment: Add this to `InitializeButtons()` after the for loop: `startButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.startButton_Click);`

Comment: added and updated the code, but still not working

Comment: Strange because I copy/pasted your code and it those work for me. (The logic of your game doesn't work tho). When I put a break point (red dot in the margin) clicking a buton do enter the `Button_Click()` function.

Comment: The code itself starts, but the game does not work properly. It shows where the number that I have to remember is, but when I click on that button nothing happens, my timer runs out and i get the message "Game Over!"

Comment: Now that the buttons do works it think a new question should be asked. The function are there and the controls are working, it's the logic of the game in itself that need to be review. Some part of the code don't works the way you wants it to work. Exemple: In the function `StartNewLevel()`, you wrote `showNumbersTimer.Tick += ShowNumbersTimer_Tick;` which create an eventHandler for showNumbersTimer when it trigger Tick. But in your function `ShowNumbersTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` you call `EndLevel()` wiich triger dans `ClearButtons()` so no button as a Text equat to "1".

Comment: Updated the code, but I want to note that the buttons are still not working

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your game, but it may not exactly do what you wanted.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int MaxLevel = 25;
        private const int ShowTimeMilliseconds = 1000;
        private const int InitialTimeSeconds = 15;

        private Button[] buttons;
        private int currentLevel;
        private int currentPlayerLevel;
        private bool gameStarted;
        private bool showingNumbers;
        private Timer showNumbersTimer;
        private Timer gameTimer;
        private Random random;
        private List<string> toRememberOrder = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeButtons();
            random = new Random();
        }

        private void InitializeButtons()
        {
            buttons = new Button[] { button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12, button13, button14, button15, button16, button17, button18, button19, button20, button21, button22, button23, button24, button25, button26 };

            foreach (var button in buttons)
            {
                button.Click += Button_Click;
            }

            startButton.Click += startButton_Click;
        }

        private void InitializeGame()
        {
            currentPlayerLevel = 1;
            currentLevel = 1;
            UpdateLevelLabel();
        }

        private void StartGame()
        {
            gameStarted = true;
            gameTimer = new Timer();
            gameTimer.Interval = 1000;
            gameTimer.Tick += GameTimer_Tick;
            gameTimer.Start();

            InitializeGame();

            int randomButtonIndex = random.Next(0, currentLevel * currentLevel);

            foreach (Button button in buttons)
            {
                button.Text = string.Empty;
            }

            ShuffleButtons();

            //buttons[randomButtonIndex].Text = "1";

            StartNewLevel();

            startButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void ShuffleButtons()
        {
            int n = buttons.Length;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = random.Next(n + 1);
                Button value = buttons[k];
                buttons[k] = buttons[n];
                buttons[n] = value;
            }
        }

        private void StartNewLevel()
        {
            showingNumbers = true;
            ClearButtons();
            int randomButtonIndex;
            List<int> indexUsed = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < currentPlayerLevel; i++)
            {
                randomButtonIndex = GetRandomIndexNotUse(indexUsed);
                indexUsed.Add(randomButtonIndex);
                buttons[randomButtonIndex].Text = (i+1).ToString();
                buttons[randomButtonIndex].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                buttons[randomButtonIndex].Enabled = true;
                toRememberOrder.Add(buttons[randomButtonIndex].Name);
            }

            //buttons[randomButtonIndex].Text = "1";
            show_num = currentPlayerLevel;
            showNumbersTimer = new Timer();
            showNumbersTimer.Interval = ShowTimeMilliseconds;
            showNumbersTimer.Tick += ShowNumbersTimer_Tick;
            showNumbersTimer.Start();
        }
        
        private int GetRandomIndexNotUse(List<int> indexUsed)
        {
            int randomIndex = random.Next(0, buttons.Length - 1);
            if(indexUsed.Contains(randomIndex) == true)
            {
                randomIndex = GetRandomIndexNotUse(indexUsed);
            }
            return randomIndex;
        }

        private void EndLevel()
        {
            showingNumbers = false;
            showNumbersTimer.Stop();
            ClearButtons();
            EnableButtons();
        }

        private void EndGame()
        {
            gameStarted = false;
            gameTimer.Stop();
            currentPlayerLevel = 0;
            UpdateLevelLabel();
            MessageBox.Show("Game Over!");
        }

        private void UpdateLevelLabel()
        {
            textBox1.Text = $"Level: {currentPlayerLevel}";
        }

        private int show_num;
        private void ShowNumbersTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (show_num == 0)
            {
                int index;
                for (int i = 0; i < currentPlayerLevel; i++)
                {
                    index = Array.FindIndex(buttons, button => button.Text == (i+1).ToString());
                    buttons[index].BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
                    buttons[index].Text = string.Empty;
                }
                showingNumbers = false;
                gameTimer.Start();
            }
            show_num--;
            //EndLevel();
        }

        private int initialTimeSeconds = InitialTimeSeconds;

        private void GameTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            initialTimeSeconds--;

            if (initialTimeSeconds < 0)
            {
                gameTimer.Stop();
                EndGame();
            }

            UpdateTimerLabel();
        }

        private void UpdateTimerLabel()
        {
            textBox2.Text = initialTimeSeconds.ToString();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;

            if (showingNumbers)
                return;


            if(button.Name == toRememberOrder.First())
            {
                toRememberOrder.Remove(button.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                gameTimer.Stop();
                EndGame();
            }
            if(toRememberOrder.Count() == 0)
            {
                gameTimer.Stop();
                Timer_Reset();
                currentPlayerLevel++;
                UpdateLevelLabel();
                StartNewLevel();
            }
        }

        private void DisableButtons()
        {
            foreach (Button button in buttons)
            {
                button.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void EnableButtons()
        {
            foreach (Button button in buttons)
            {
                button.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void ClearButtons()
        {
            foreach (Button button in buttons)
            {
                button.Text = string.Empty;
                button.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            }
        }

        private void Timer_Reset()
        {
            initialTimeSeconds = InitialTimeSeconds;
            UpdateTimerLabel();
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!gameStarted)
            {
                InitializeGame();
                StartGame();
            }
        }
    }
}
```